# rails 3: custom routes in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to get link to user like: `/chicago/123-olegpasko` .
In my helper:

```
def users_path(user)
  "/#{if user.city; user.city.name; else; "city";end}/#{user.to_param}"
end
```

How can I create a right routes?

Now I have something like:

```
match 'dontknow/:id' => 'users#show', :as => :users
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple:

```
match ':name/:id' => 'users#show', :as => :users
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Railcasts about friendly_url](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid)

Also take a look at the [routes casts](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=routes)

Comment: Thanks! Links are useful, but not for my situation :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple add this lines in you model:

```
def to_param
  "#{id}-#{name.parameterize}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but with my `to_param` is all Ok. My problem is in `user.city`. When I click to user link I getting route error.